# Electromagnetic energy harvesting designing problems

Tags: mechanical, energy-harvesting, vibration, mechanical-assembly

We designed a very simple energy harvester made of a little magnet that moves inside a coil.

We have a vibrating environment moving at 12 Hz with 10 millimeters peak-to-peak. Our pcb will be attached to the vibrating table and will be potted to avoid problems to the components soldered onto the pcb.

Currently only a gyroscope, an accelerometer and a bluetooth module are on it.

The problems derived from the rectification are not the major issues.

Our PCB has to be attached to this vibrating table, that works 24/7. We realized that our energy harvester has to support ca 14 millions vibrations in just two weeks.

- Is this enrmous number of vibration going to destroy my energy harvester?
- Should we use another solution (we thought of a battery solution but there are other problems that I cover here: [Are Lithium Thionyl Chloride Battery usable in my vibrating environment? Are they safe?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/210950/are-lithium-thionyl-chloride-battery-usable-in-my-vibrating-environment-are-the))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume your "10 mm amplitude" is peak to peak.  The position can therefore be described as

P = 5 sin(2π12t) [mm]

or

P = 5 sin(ωt) [mm], where ω = 24π

The velocity is the first derivative of position:

V = 5ω cos(ωt) [mm/s]

The acceleration is the second derivative of position and the first derivative of velocity:

A = -5ω<sup>2</sup> sin(ωt) [mm/s<sup>2</sup>]

Plugging in our value of ω, the maximum acceleration is

Max A = 5ω<sup>2</sup> mm/s<sup>2</sup> = 5(24π)<sup>2</sup> mm/s<sup>2</sup> = 28,400 mm/s<sup>2</sup> = 28.4 m/s<sup>2</sup> = 2.9 g

3 g isn't *that* much.  Of course you have to consider that this will be applied repetitively, but still, it should be possible to design something that can withstand many many 3 g cycles.

Comment: Thank you very much. The amplitude I was wrongly talking about is peak to peak, I'm going to update the post. My second question is: what measures should we follow to get this energy harvester to last two years 'always on'?

Comment: @Three: That's a mechanical engineering question.

Comment: Do you think I have to move the question or make a separate one?